# Sharepoint Workflows in background

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs, workflow-activity

I'm just curious, I was reading an article [here](http://www.egroup-us.com/sharepoint-2010-workflow-error-due-to-heavy-load), and in the third paragraph it states

> "If you didn’t know, there are quite a few workflows that run in the background all the time. "

I was just wondering what these workflows are, and where to find them. I am reasonably new to SharePoint, and had never come across anything about workflows running in the background.

Does anybody know much about these?

Jason

Edit: I have continued scouring the internet, and all I can find is [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc678870%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on microsoft's website about timer jobs, but still nothing on workflows running in the background.

However, this article has piqued my interest and I am now also wondering, is there a way to see which of these timer jobs are currently running or queued to run on my SharePoint installation?